# Condition is true but it's ignoring the statement Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

The **if condition** is **true**, but it is ignoring the if condition and proceeds to the next methods under this file.

Assume that value attribute of Name element is already **NULL**

```
string GetValue = Name.GetAttribute("value");
// assume that value attribute of Name element is already NULL

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValue))
{
Assert.AreEqual(ElementLabel.GetCssValue("color"), InputColor);
}
else
{
<code>
}
```

Comment: have you tried viewing the String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValue) ?

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code for this method, if possible. Even if all you do is stub out example code.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The `value` attribute is `null` because it doesn't exist, or is it `null` because you have `value="null"` in the html?

Comment: @VirojFernando Yes, it is empty, before this condition is performed, the Name.Clear(); is being performed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Will post it in a few minutes, thanks.

Comment: @Guy value attribute is null/empty, before this condition is performed, the Name.Clear(); is being performed.

Comment: @LadysMuswashands using `Name.Clear();` doesn't necessarily mean the value is null or empty. Debug it and check what `GetValue` value is.